# Pandas Datareader - Module not found after installation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, conda, pandas-datareader

I am trying to install & use Pandas-Datareader, but when after I have installed it, I receive a `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try and import it.

I am using Jupyter Notebook installed using Anaconda - so use the conda installer to install new packages.

After typing `source activate ipykernel_py3` to activate the Python3 kernel environment, I have used `conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader=0.4.0` to install Pandas-Datareader.

If I try `conda list`, then I get the output below - which shows Pandas_Datareader installed.

But if I try the command ```import pandas_datareader as pdr`` (as found in documentation [here](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), then I get an error message

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'`

(This happens in both the Jupyter notebook and in the Python3 interpreter running in this environment.

Can anybody help?

Many thanks

---

** Conda List output:**

`# packages in environment at /Users/Chris/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py3:
#
appnope                   0.1.0                    py36_0

beautifulsoup4            4.5.3                    py36_0

cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0

decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0

freetype                  2.5.5                         2

icu                       54.1                          0

ipykernel                 4.6.1                    py36_0

ipython                   6.0.0                    py36_0

ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0

jupyter_client            5.0.1                    py36_0

jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py36_0

libpng                    1.6.27                        0

matplotlib                2.0.2               np112py36_0

mkl                       2017.0.1                      0

numpy                     1.12.1                   py36_0

openssl                   1.0.2k                        1

pandas                    0.20.1              np112py36_0

pandas-datareader         0.4.0                    py36_0    anaconda
path.py                   10.3.1                   py36_0

pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_0

pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0

pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1

prompt_toolkit            1.0.14                   py36_0

ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py36_0

pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0

pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0

pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_2

python                    3.6.1                         0

python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py36_0

pytz                      2017.2                   py36_0

pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py36_0

qt                        5.6.2                         2

readline                  6.2                           2

requests                  2.14.2                   py36_0    anaconda
requests-file             1.4.1                    py36_0    anaconda
requests-ftp              0.3.1                    py36_0    anaconda
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py36_0

seaborn                   0.7.1                    py36_0

setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0

simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_1

sip                       4.18                     py36_0

six                       1.10.0                   py36_0

sqlite                    3.13.0                        0

tk                        8.5.18                        0

tornado                   4.5.1                    py36_0

traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0

wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0

wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0

xz                        5.2.2                         1

zlib                      1.2.8                         3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the notebook in the `ipykernel_py3` environment?

```
  source activate ipykernel_py3
  ipython notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type

pip install pandas_datareader in your anaconda prompt

and try running it again in jupyter.